# lapply to multiple arguments in a function

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

I am using the lapply function in the following form:

```
y=rnorm(10)
x1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
x2=c(5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)
x3=c(7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11)

t1 <- outer(x1, unique(x1), '<=')
t2 <- outer(x2, unique(x2), '<=')
t3 <- outer(x3, unique(x3), '<=')
lapply(seq_along(unique(x1)), function(idx) t(y*t1[,idx]*t2) %*% t3)
```

Since I am an R beginner, I am having problems to generalize the above lapply call to add another variable, that is, now lapply would call a function of 2 arguments. This is what I have tried to do:

```
x4=c(7,6,6,5,9,5,10,1,1,2)
t4 <- outer(x4, unique(x4), '<=')
lapply(list(idx1=seq_along(unique(x1)),idx4=seq_along(unique(x4))),
       function(idx1,idx4) t(y*t1[,idx1]*t2) %*% t3*t4[,idx4])
```

The idea here is the following: I fix idx1, and then use the lapply function for each idx4. Then, for the next idx1, the same. I should be something like a nested lapply.

So far, I am not able to come up with the correct way of doing this. Would anyone provide any tip?

PS.: This question is related to one I previously asked, but my problem here is that I am not able to generalize the previous answer to 4 dimensions, given that the way it is structures, the lapply structure is not the same. Henceforth, I am now asking for a tip on how to make this generalization. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a way to solve it, nesting two lapply functions.

```
lapply(seq_along(unique(x)), function(idx){lapply(seq_along(unique(r)),
                                              function(idr) t(y*t1[,idx]*t2)%*%(t3
                                              *t4[,idr]))})
```

This defintely solve my problem. If anyone has a cleaner solution, please post it.